# IOS: UIImageView in UICollectionView not displaying certain jpg images

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uicollectionview, jpeg

I have a UICollectionView in which I have embedded a UIImageView.

The collection shows all images that are held in the applications documents directory

```
NSArray *paths =         NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Some supplied images are copied from the Main Bundle into the documents directory when the app loads and these display fine.

I have functionality to allow an image to be selected from the photos saved on the device. I am using the standard UIImagePickerController and then save the selected image to the applications documents folder with the following code

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSString *dateTime = [self getDateTimeKey];

    NSString *newImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@%@%@",@"z",dateTime, @".JPG"];
    BOOL saveStatus=YES;

    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    NSData  *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, 1);
    NSError *saveError;

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];


    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:newImageName];

    saveStatus = [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&saveError];

    if (saveStatus == NO)
    {
        NSLog(@"Save Failed - |%@|\n", saveError);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Save Worked\n");
    }
    selectedImageName = NULL;

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

The save works and via debug statements I can see the file has been written to the documents directory. I can also see that the ‘cellForRowAtIndexPath’ method of the collectionview is being called to create a UIImage for the saved file. I have also downloaded the container from a test device and been able to view the image so I know the image is ‘valid’

However the UIImageView in the collection view won’t display it – there is just an empty UIImageView !! Any thoughts ?

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: Does a `UIImage` actually get created in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: 1) It's not  JPEG stream but the file has an extension indicating JPEG; 2) It's a JPEG stream but not in a file format recognized. I'd run some JPEG dump program over the ones that don't display and see what's in the stream.

Comment: @IanMacDonald - yes the UIImageView is there as it is part of the cell created in the storyboard but the Image is not dispalyed

Comment: @user3344003 - I can open the image in 'Preview' is that enough to prove it is a valid stream ?

Comment: @Carl: you didn't answer my question.

Comment: @IanMacDonald - Apologies: The image is created outside of cellForRowAtIndexPath. The cellForRowAtIndexPath just displays it

Comment: It would be in a valid stream but one that is not recognized by UIImageView